# How to connect my program in Docker with local databese MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, docker

On my Ubuntu20 I have configured MySQL and i have written a python program to communicate with database. I would like to run the Python program in the docker so that it can communicate with the database located locally in the system. Below I paste my Dockerfile content.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /my_service

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app ./app

CMD ["python", "./app/main.py"]
```

But when I run command to run docker conteiner:

```
sudo docker run -t -p 13000:13000 my_service
```

My application inside tell me that cant connect to MySQL database. How Could I fix it? I mappped port 13000 because my aplication use it to tcp communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of achieving this. Most of them are discussed in [this other SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach).

I think one of the easiest ways to achieve this would be to point from your docker container to the host using the built-in DNS name:

```
host.docker.internal
```

The chosen option would depend on the version of docker you use. Check the linked issue for more information.